# AS3 - Memory management

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a question regarding AS3 memory management I wonder if anyone could help me with.

Supposing I created an instance variable for a Class, in this case or type Sound:

```
public class SoundStore extends Sprite{

var s:Sound;
```

Then within various class functions I referenced this variable multiple times, each time I wanted to load in a new sound:

```
s = new Sound();
```

Am I correct in thinking that each time I created a new Sound I would be overwriting the previous allocated memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. AS3 is a garbage collected language, which uses reference counting to dispose of unused objects.

The `s` variable is, internally, a pointer to a block of memory that contains a `Sound` object. Every time you do `s = new Sound()` AS3 will create a new `Sound` object in memory and set the `s` pointer to the address of that object. The old object still exists in memory. If you have no references to the old object, the garbage collector will dispose of the object at some point, usually its next collection round. This means that at any point in time you may have multiple `Sound` objects in memory that aren't being referenced but that are still using up resources. The garbage collector is designed to periodically trawl through all allocated objects and dispose them if there are no references to them.

Here's a nice article on the GC in Flash / AS3: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html

Comment: OK thanks. I understand that I don't have specific control over when GC is run.

If I did the following would this help my memory management:

try {
s = null;
} catch (e:Error)
{}

s = new Sound();

Comment: No. s would stop pointing at that instance of Sound, but it will still be there sitting in Memory until Nothing else within your entire application is pointing at it. (This includes Events, unless `useWeakRefereces` is set to true).

Comment: You *can* call `System.gc()` to force a garbage collection in Flash 10 and later, but it is a **REALLY** bad idea. It totally screws the performance and isn't even guaranteed to do anything outside of debug.

Comment: So what would be the most memory efficient way to set up my code if I am expecting to be loading in multiple MP3 files, one at a time and playing them, again only one at a time.

Would it be as above, ensuring that the current s had no references pointing at it before I created a new Sound and allocated it to s?

Comment: Just set all references of it to null and carry on as normal. The garbage collector will make its rounds frequently enough for it not to be a problem. The only thing *you* have to worry about is making sure that all references to it are cleared.